# SQL - How can I find duplicates from two tables?

Tags: sql-server

I have a problem where I need write a SQL that displays the duplicate PlayistIDs and PlaylistNames as well as any associated TrackIDs.

- The Playlist table contains the columns PlaylistID and PlaylistName.
- The PlaylistTrack table contains the columns PlaylistID and TrackID.
- The Track table contains the column TrackID.

The only thing I tried was to work backwards by taking a look at all the data by running the code below. Then hopefully isolate what I'm looking for.

Looking at Stackoverflow they recommended using `HAVING COUNT(*) > 1`, but its to no avail for me.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

```
SELECT *
FROM Playlist P
JOIN PlaylistTrack PP
    ON P.PlaylistId = PP.PlaylistId
JOIN Track T
    ON PT.TrackId = T.TrackId
```

The results should be:

- PlaylistName - Music & TV Shows
- PlaylistID - 8 and 10
- TrackID = 3503 and 2819.

The output above are the duplicates I am looking for. I ran the code above, copied it to excel, and filtered to see what the duplicates are.

Comment: It would be better to help you if you will provide sample data in text/table format and also desired output in table format.

Comment: Could you post the sample data, my friend?

Comment: Would you be able to tell, why ""HAVING COUNT(*) > 1"" is no available for you? what you mean here, you want solution without HAVING clause or any other reason?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't like HAVING, why not ROW_NUMBER with PARTITION.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT P.PlaylistID,P.PlaylistName,T.TrackID,dupid=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY P.PlaylistId,T.TrackId ORDER BY T.TrackId)
    FROM Playlist P
    JOIN PlaylistTrack PP
        ON P.PlaylistId = PP.PlaylistId
    JOIN Track T
        ON PT.TrackId = T.TrackId
)ax
where dupid>1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join multiple copies of the tables together

```
SELECT pp1.TrackId, p1.PlaylistName, pp1.PlaylistID, p2.PlaylistName, pp2.PlaylistID 
FROM Playlist P1
INNER JOIN PlaylistTrack PP1
    ON P1.PlaylistId = PP1.PlaylistId
INNER JOIN PlaylistTrack PP2
    ON (PP1.PlaylistId != PP2.PlaylistId AND pp1.TrackId = pp2.TrackId)
INNER JOIN Playlist P2
    ON P2.PlaylistId = PP2.PlaylistId
ORDER BY pp1.TrackId;
```

This would give you the results where a TrackId appears on multiple playlists.

It has a slight problem that you will get duplicate results, just reversed ie. you would get:

```
Trackid  Playlist1Id  Playlist2Id
3503      8           10
3503     10            8
```

If this is going in the right direction, you can extend the sql to remove the duplication if need be.